# Stream large table from to another table using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to copy from table from one table to another.  So i want to stream the large data in and as it comes in I want to copy the contents of that data to another table. Its more then just a straight copy.  I will probably massage the data a bit and then copy it over to the new table. The problem that I'm having is that **row** event keeps firing and I can't control it.  I tried using async and await where I was hoping to make it stop but does not seem to be working.  I can't control an event from firing or not.   This is what I have so far.  So basically I want to simulate a cursor in MSSQL.  I don't want to download all the data and then do operations on it.

I'm not showing the massaging of the data below since I just want to see if I can copy data from one table to another.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sql = require('mssql');
var sql2 = require('mssql');
var Request = require('tedious').Request; 
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;  
var SqlString = require('sqlstring');

const config = {
    user: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    server: 'xxxx\\',
    port: 'xxxx',
    database: 'xxxx',
    options: {
        instanceName: 'sql2014'
    }
};


function insertRecord(pool, record){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        const request = pool.request();

        request.input('invoice_id', sql.Int, record.invoice_id);

        request.query('INSERT INTO _invoice_temp(invoice_id)  VALUES(@invoice_id)', (err, result) => {
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }

            resolve(1);
        });
     });
}

async function main() {
    try
    {
        let pool = (await sql.connect(config));
        const request = pool.request();
        request.stream = true;
        request.query('select * from invoice');

        var data = await request.on('row', row => {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                    resolve(row);
                });
            });

        await insertRecord(pool, data);

    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);  
    }
};

main();
```

Comment: Sorry in my example I'm not showing massaging of the data.  I was trying to see it was possible in my code first to copy data from one table to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna copy table to another table from same database, then you should accomplish it under the db level only. It's not a good approach to fetch data from database, then process and insert it to that db by some server side technologies like Node.js. So you can use raw SQL queries to do your job.

Copy all columns from one table to another table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Copy only some columns from one table into another table:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

You can read more about it in the below link:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp